# Is there a GUI-based MIME-type editor?

Tags: 18.04, gui, ubuntu-gnome, mime-type, editor

I remember seeing on some other distro this file type editor. What it had was a table, containing MIME types, their associated names (e.g. `text/plain` would show as "plain text document"), icons, and file extensions. Since then I have not been able to find it or anything even remotely similar to it. The irony is it was on Debian, and everyone knows that Ubuntu and Debian use the same code base. I wonder if anyone would be able to find it or even make something like it?

Comment: gedit? >:-D  "Tweaks" used to allow you to select multiple types. Maybe that was it? Does not do that anymore though